# Does Abel's identity require that the linear ODE have continuous coefficients?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does Abel's identity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_identity#Direct_proof) require that the linear ODE have continuous coefficients?

I am specifically looking at the general proof in the above wiki article, and it does not seem that continuity of $p_1,...,p_{n-1}$ has been employed (except for perhaps for integration of $p_{n-1}$).  Moreover in another book the coefficients was said to be always non zero.  Can anyone clarify the conditions on the linear ODE, for Abel's identity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One likes the coefficients to be continuous, and $p_n$, if non-trivial, to be non-zero, as then the equivalent first-order system has the Lipschitz property required by the Picard-Lindelöf existence-and-uniqueness theorem.

The continuity of the other coefficients is thus required for the existence of the basis solutions. For the integral in the Abel identity itself it is sufficient that $p_{n-1}$ is Riemann integrable.

One can extend this without problem to piecewise continuous coefficients with finite jumps, and perhaps to more general functions with finite total variation. Key is that some existence theorem can be proven.